# Position of the search field

Tags: local.xml

I would like the search box to the left position next to the user account. I have created a local.xml with the following content :

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
<reference name="header">
<action method="unsetChild">
<name>topSearch</name>
</action>
</reference>

<reference name="header">
<block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Here the search field end up back at the same place . How do I position correct?
Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

in **header.phtml**

```
<div class="quick-access">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
            <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        </div>
```

move this block to **$this->getChildHtml('topSearch')**

```
<div class="quick-access">

                <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your templates `app/design/frontend/YOURBASE/YOURTHEME/template/page/html/header.phtml` and look for: (based on 1.9 RWD theme)

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

And move it to where you want it in that file.